# Exception: Job Failed with status:3 when copying data from Oracle to HDFS through sqoop2

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop2

I am trying to use Sqoop2 to copy data from an Oracle 11g2 server to HDFS.

The link to Oracle *seems* to work, as it will complain if I use invalid credentials. The definition is as follows:

```
    link with id 14 and name OLink (Enabled: true, Created by xxx at 2/9/16 2:48 PM, Updated by xxx at 2/11/16 10:08 AM)
Using Connector generic-jdbc-connector with id 4
  Link configuration
    JDBC Driver Class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    JDBC Connection String: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=5999)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=abc)))
    Username: xxx
    Password:
    JDBC Connection Properties:
```

(The weird port number is here because I need to use a reverse tunneling to access the database for now. It will be fixed soon)

The job definition is the following

```
Job with id 2 and name Test OLink (Enabled: true, Created by xxx at 2/9/16 2:56 PM, Updated by xxx at 2/11/16 10:58 AM)
Using link id 14 and Connector id 4
  From database configuration
    Schema name: xxx
    Table name: t_name
    Table SQL statement:
    Table column names:
    Partition column name: CL_ID
    Null value allowed for the partition column: false
    Boundary query:
  Throttling resources
    Extractors: 3
    Loaders: 3
  ToJob configuration
    Override null value:
    Null value:
    Output format: TEXT_FILE
    Compression format: DEFAULT
    Custom compression format:
    Output directory: /tmp
```

When I start the job (with verbose mode set to true), it lists all the column name and types of the remote table (meaning the connectivity to Oracle is OK), but the job fails, for example

```
2016-02-11 10:44:42 UTC: BOOTING  - Progress is not available
2016-02-11 10:44:59 UTC: RUNNING  - 0.00 %
2016-02-11 10:45:09 UTC: RUNNING  - 0.00 %
2016-02-11 10:45:19 UTC: RUNNING  - 0.00 %
2016-02-11 10:45:29 UTC: FAILED
Exception: Job Failed with status:3
Stack trace: Task failed task_1450719316904_0239_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
```

The logs show the following:

```
2016-02-11 10:44:59,651 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: getResources() for application_1450719316904_0239: ask=1 release= 0 newContainers=0 finishedContainers=0 resourcelimit=<memory:56320, vCores:37> knownNMs=5
2016-02-11 10:45:04,775 INFO [Socket Reader #1 for port 54706] SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for job_1450719316904_0239 (auth:SIMPLE)
2016-02-11 10:45:04,803 INFO [IPC Server handler 5 on 54706] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: JVM with ID : jvm_1450719316904_0239_m_000002 asked for a task
2016-02-11 10:45:04,803 INFO [IPC Server handler 5 on 54706] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: JVM with ID: jvm_1450719316904_0239_m_000002 given task: attempt_1450719316904_0239_m_000000_0
2016-02-11 10:45:06,494 INFO [IPC Server handler 5 on 54706] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1450719316904_0239_m_000000_0 is : 0.0
2016-02-11 10:45:06,503 FATAL [IPC Server handler 6 on 54706] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1450719316904_0239_m_000000_0 - exited : org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: MAPRED_EXEC_0017:Error occurs during extractor run
    at org.apache.sqoop.job.mr.SqoopMapper.run(SqoopMapper.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: GENERIC_JDBC_CONNECTOR_0001:Unable to get a connection
    at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcExecutor.<init>(GenericJdbcExecutor.java:59)
    at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcExtractor.extract(GenericJdbcExtractor.java:50)
    at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcExtractor.extract(GenericJdbcExtractor.java:38)
    at org.apache.sqoop.job.mr.SqoopMapper.run(SqoopMapper.java:95)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcExecutor.<init>(GenericJdbcExecutor.java:51)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:439)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:454)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:693)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)
    ... 22 more
```

The software versions are

- Sqoop 1.99.5-cdh5.4.8 source revision 5d69aef6c630a68db47724e4541e02983ade3d67
  Compiled by jenkins on Thu Oct 15 08:50:55 PDT 2015
- java version "1.7.0_67"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Any clue on how to troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Sqoop job starts up, it will connect from the machine you are running the Sqoop command on to the Oracle machine to query the tables and build the Sqoop job.

When the map-reduce phase starts running, each datanode in the cluster that is running a map-reduce task will need to connect to the database. From those errors, it looks like your datanodes cannot connect to Oracle, but the machine you are initiating the job from can.

Can you confirm connectivity from all the datanodes to Oracle?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of the nodes. I'll see with the network admins to open the ports for the nodes as well, and will revert.

Comment: It was indeed because the data nodes could not access it. Now the jobs can run.